# Why floating calculation and casting shows different result in debug and release configuration?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, floating-point

This is really a weird bug to me and it took me long time to figure out what's happening. To simplify things and reproduce, just create a empty win32 console application using VS2005 and use this code in the main method:

```
float a = 411.00418f;
float b = 1.0f;
float c = 0.076279849f;
unsigned short result = (unsigned short)( (a-b)/c );
unsigned short result2 = (unsigned short)( (float)((a-b)/c) );
// Debug: 5374, 5375
// Release: 5374, 5374
printf("%d, %d\n", result, result2);
```

Why result2 shows different value in debug/release mode?

Answer (score 10):

In MSVC, the default floating-point mode is `precise (/fp:precise)`. Meaning that the optimizer may do certain optimizations to improve accuracy or performance.

Try changing mode to `strict (/fp:strict)`. This will make the compiler follow the strict floating-point rules on rounding and such.

(EDIT: `strict (/fp:strict)` doesn't seem to work in this case...)

If you look at the disassembly of the optimized build, you can see that the entire computation has been folded and optimized out.

```
push    5374                    ; 000014feH
push    5374                    ; 000014feH
push    OFFSET ??_C@_07MHMABKGB@?$CFd?0?5?$CFd?6?$AA@
call    DWORD PTR __imp__printf
add esp, 12                 ; 0000000cH
```

**EDIT : This looks like a compiler optimizer bug to me.**

Under `strict (/fp:strict)`, the following code produces different results:

```
float a = 411.00418f;
float b = 1.0f;
float c = 0.076279849f;

unsigned short result1 = (unsigned short)((float)((a-b)/c));

float d = (float)((a-b)/c);
unsigned short result2 = (unsigned short)( d );
```

Output:

```
5374, 5375
```

Pulling out the `(float)((a-b)/c)` into a separate assignment should not affect the results under `strict (/fp:strict)`.

---

**I know one of the guys who work on the MSVC optimizer. I'll send a bug report to him.**

## Update:

Here's their response:

> Hi Alex, thanks for this bug report. I’ll try to fix this for the
>   upcoming VC++ release, but it might not make it.
>
> FWIW, the bug doesn’t reproduce if you throw /arch:SSE2, and since we
>   are enabling /arch:SSE2 by default for the next VC++ release
>   (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/688736/compiler-generates-sse-instructions-without-arch-sse).
>
> So, the default behavior will show that this bug is fixed. But if
>   you revert back to the old FP model (throw /arch:IA32) the bug may
>   still be present.
>
> Eric

**So they've confirmed this as a bug.**

Comment: I set the "floating point model" to "Strict (/fp:strict)" and the result is the same. Did I miss something here?

Comment: I noticed that too. I'm trying to figure it out too. In the optimized build, the optimizer is folding all the computation. I *think* that's where it isn't respecting strict rounding behavior.

Comment: Actually my project is using C++/CLI in vs2010, so maybe that's affected too?

Comment: I'm trying to verify that `Strict (/fp:strict)` really does in fact guarantee strict FP as written in the code, before I submit this report. This shouldn't have anything to do with the CLI. It's the optimizer that isn't respecting strict floating-point.